# How do I add a new System variable in Windows 7 via the command line?

Tags: windows, windows-7, system-variable

What is the correct way to create and set a new System variable via the command line in Windows 7?

I know that it's possible through the GUI by doing the following:
`Control Panel => System => Advanced System settings => Environment variables => Add new System variable`

I have read about [SetX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.11).aspx) and this seems like correct way to do it, but I still have some questions:

- If I wanted to create an environment variable called `TNS_ADMIN` and
  set the value as the path to my `tnsnames.ora` file, would below be
  the entire command?

  `SetX TNS_ADMIN \\domain.blah\directory\DBA\OraUpdates /m`
- Would this automatically get added to the `PATH` variable? Or would I
  need to update the `PATH` variable separately after adding the new System variable?

Comment: Type setx /? and it will tell you.

Comment: Be careful about using setx.exe to update `PATH`. Do not use the current `%PATH%` value. Read the system value via `reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH`. Parse the value from the output; append to it; and set it back via `setx.exe /M PATH "%NEW_PATH%"`. Take care not to expand percent variables in the string. Of course, create a restore point before messing with the registry and experiment on a dummy variable.